# Sending Email from Locomotive CMS with Mandrill

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer, locomotivecms

Is anyone familiar with locomotivecms, I am trying to send email with mandrill and nothing makes sense. I am just using there reset email password function as the test before I create models. I assume that locomotive already has everything inplace for action:mailer I just need to add the smtp settings to the production.rb file which I have but have no luck here is my production.rb file

```
Portfolio::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Defaults to nil and saved in location specified by config.assets.prefix
  # config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # See everything in the log (default is :info)
  # config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable threaded mode
  # config.threadsafe!

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify


  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'dev.anderskitson.ca' }
# ActionMailer Config
# Setup for production - deliveries, no errors raised


  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address   => "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
    :port      => 25, # ports 587 and 2525 are also supported with STARTTLS
    :enable_starttls_auto => true, # detects and uses STARTTLS
    :user_name => "example@gmail.com",
    :password  => "4ffdsafas0oJP3PA", # SMTP password is any valid API key
    :authentication => 'login', # Mandrill supports 'plain' or 'login'
    :domain => 'dev.anderskitson.ca', # your domain to identify your server when connecting
  }




end
```

Comment: have you solved that? I've written a config and sent an email using rails console, but locomotive doesn't send any email though(

Answer (score -2):

You have a comma in the last line of the smtp settings which shouldn't be there. Try removing that.

If it doesn't work after that, please share the output of your production.log.

Comment: ruby syntax allows last comma in hashes and arrays